# Sharing of data between hook and portlet in differen war file

Tags: liferay-6

How to share data between processaction method of base strutsportlet action and post login event through session

```
public class CustomLoginAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {
public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
                           PortletConfig portletConfig,
                           ActionRequest actionRequest,
                          ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay=null ;
    User userObject = null; 
    LoginPojo loginPojo=null;
    String controlPanelUrl = null;

    String userName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "login");
    String password = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "password");
    String domain = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "domain");
    String forceLogin = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "forcelogin");
```

how to use the data in run method

```
public class CustomLoginPostAction extends Action {
public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ActionException {
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `PortalUtil`, you can get `HttpServletRequest` and hence session. So set session attributes in `CustomLoginAction` class and get that session attribute in `CustomLoginPostAction` from session [get session from request]